# how to remove trailing or leading charaters in a mysql query?

Tags: mysql, database, replace

I have a Japanese dictionary table, the English words that correspond to the Japanese look something like this:

```
jap       eng                   marks     id
テクスト    /  text/ text book/     (n)     31112
```

I want to remove the leading and trailing slashes and spaces. it almost always have leading and trailing slashes but also have valid slashes separating the multiple English meanings. How can i write a query that will remove a given string if it is leading or trailing? In this case the "/ " is leading and "/" is trailing but sometimes there is multiple slashes on the end or front and sometimes with or without unnecessary spaces

so im thinking if I had some query like

```
set eng = REPLACE_LEADING_OR_TRAILING(" /", "", eng)
```

i could just query it with all the possibilities

```
REPLACE_LEADING_OR_TRAILING("//", "", eng)
REPLACE_LEADING_OR_TRAILING(" /", "", eng)
REPLACE_LEADING_OR_TRAILING(" / ", "", eng)
REPLACE_LEADING_OR_TRAILING("/ ", "", eng)
REPLACE_LEADING_OR_TRAILING("/", "", eng)
```

i know about the REPLACE() function but i can't see how i would do it with that because of the valid slashes in between multiple English meanings.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use the [TRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) function:

To remove spaces, just call it with no other parameter than your field/variable

```
SELECT TRIM(eng)
```

To remove another character, use this version instead:

```
SELECT TRIM(BOTH '/' FROM eng);
```

Comment: and this will not remove the slashes that are in the middle somewhere, correct?

Comment: For that perhaps regex in MySQL may be used

Comment: @user1397417 that is right, it will only remove trailing or leading characters. FYI, you can place `BOTH` in the second version by `LEADING` or `TRAILING` if you only want to remove those characters from either side